# `peewee` how to get the parent model of a foreign key

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

Let's say I create several `pweewee` [link](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) models

```
db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')
class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    class Meta:
        database = db # This model uses the "people.db" database.
class Pet(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='pets')
    name = CharField()
    animal_type = CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the "people.db" database
class Car(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='cars')
    model = CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the "people.db" database
```

As you can see, both `Car` and `Pet` models are connected to a `Person`. Let's say that I have an object which can be either
a `car` or a `pet`. I'm not sure whic, but I know that the `owner` field is a foreign field. How can I get the parent model of that field?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to find the answer.

`obj._meta.fields` will give us a dictionary, where the key is the field name and the value is the field object. This means, that we can get the field object by:

```
owner_field = obj._meta.fields['owner']
```

Now, to get the model and the field it is related to, we need to do `owner_field.rel_model` and `owner_field.rel_field`